# Windows 7 RDP not working for a specific server

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am having trouble connecting to a Remote Server from my Windows 7 machine. Whenever I try to connect, I get the error saying:

This computer cant't connect to the remote computer.

Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator.

Here are all the things I've done:

1. I can connect to another server in the same subnet with the same credentials.
2. From the server from step 1, I can RDP to the server in question successfully with the same credentials.
3. I can connect to multiple other servers in the network.
4. Other people can successfully RDP into the server that I am having trouble connecting to.
5. I have made sure that I am not hitting the simultaneous connections limit.
6. I have verified the RD Session Host Configurations are consistent across both the servers I can connect to and the one that I cannot.

There are no events logged regarding this error on either my local machine or the remote one that I am trying to connect to. This seems to be a very generic error as Google searching has not provided many answers. Does anyone have any idea on what I can try next to get this issue resolved? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behaviour from Win7 64bit clients. Disabling sound and printer had no effect. 
Weird.
For further troubleshooting I  disabled all non-microsoft services from start-up.
Success. 
I disabled all bluetooth services from starting up and this fixed the problem.

Maybe this helps you too.